# Do I need .NET 1.0/1.1 to run apps built on those versions, or can I upgrade to 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, backwards-compatibility, .net-1.1, .net-1.0

We have many new computers and have some needed old apps created using .net 1.0 and some created with .net 1.1.  Will these apps work if I install only .net 3.5?

The applications are desktop apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642301/do-you-need-both-net-3-5-and-4-0-installed-or-just-net-4 might be of help to you.

Comment: Depending on OS, you might have everything installed already.

Comment: From that question, it looks like doing some testing is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if the applications were compiled to specifically require the older version. If yes, then you need to install the framework version against which the applications were built in order to have them run correctly. If not, they should be able to pick up 2.0 if that's installed.

[See this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/20/9557946.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik no.   .NET X can run apps for older X, but only if older X >=2.0

1.0 and 1.1 must seen as a different framework