# cannot install .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, .net-3.5

I already have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and VS 2010 SP1. I'm using Windows 7.

Then, I noticed in my Installed Programs in Control Panel that only the following were the installed .NET Frameworks:

- Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended.

For some reasons, when I was installing PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008, it says that I need to install .NET Framework 3.5.

When I tried to use dotnetfx35.exe, it just unpacks the installer, but doesn't proceed with the setup process.

Is this just because I'm using Windows 7? Or is there a proper way of setting up .NET Framework 3.5?

Thanks!

Comment: It is pre-installed on Windows 7, it won't appear in Installed Programs.  Click "Turn Windows features on or off" to see it.  Your problem with PowerCommands is unguessable.

Comment: I agree. But this is odd. If Windows 7 is already pre-installed, how do I see it? Is it in the Programs and Features of Control Panel? I installed a .NET verification test and it says that it passed, however I can't understand fully how can it say that it already has been installed. Any thoughts?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/anBbM.png

Answer (score 8):

Newer operating systems (Windows 7+ afaik) do not (cannot) use installation files for the .NET 3.5 framework.  Also, the 3.5 framework does not necessarily show in add/remove programs.  Instead, you "turn on" the feature.  Another detail is that .NET 3.5 includes 3.0 and 2.0 frameworks.  In other words, .NET framework 3.0 and 2.0 do not require separate installs.

To "add"/verify installation of .NET 3.5 in Windows Server 2008 R2:

> Go to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off >
>   Roles > Add Role Service (little button off to the right) > Ensure
>   ".NET Framework 3.5.1" is checked > Click "next" until you can click
>   "install".

The process should be similar in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Even though You have installed DOTNET 4.0 version for some applications you need 3.5 .net framework.

Just download and install DOT NET 3.5 SP1 (not just 3.5) from here [1 here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22)

(Note: Refer [Stack Overflow - .dot net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642301/do-you-need-both-net-3-5-and-4-0-installed-or-just-net-4) for more details!)